# How to download a folder containing multiple files on an FTP server to a desktop?

Tags: windows-7, ftp

I want to download a folder which contains hundreds of files that are hosted on an ftp server to my Windows 7 desktop. I've never used FTP before, so I am not sure where to start.

Comment: Navigate to FTP site, Page menu->View in Explorer, Copy files to desktop. Or get a real client like [Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

FTP protocol doesn't support directory download.
Most FTP clients (AFAIK, not including standard command line tools "ftp") allow to download directories by getting their listing recursively and downloading files one by one automatically.

There is a plenty of different clients. For instance, [filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) - free and open source.

Comment: you can also use the mget command if you are limited to command line and there is no directory structure

Comment: If you come here from Google, make sure to read the answer below, which notes that even the built-in Explorer can do this, without having to install an additional tool.

Answer (score 54):

1. Open an Explorer window. Click on the `Start` menu, then select `My Computer`.
2. Type the ftp url in the the address bar. For example:

   ```
   ftp://mirror.anl.gov/pub/ubuntu
   ```
3. If a login is necessary, a dialog box will appear.
4. A listing of all directories and files of the server will appear.
5. Copy the files just as you would with a normal folder.

Comment: _If a login is necessary, a dialog box will appear._ - this didn't happen for me. Instead, I needed to do   `ftp://username:password@ftp.example.com/dir1/dir2/`

Answer (score 1):

Map network drive your FTP location - explained [here](http://cybernetnews.com/cybernotes-map-a-ftp-to-a-drive-in-windows/) then you can open it using explorer. Copy your folder as usual --
Thiru

Answer (score 0):

If you archive (zip) the directory, you can get the archive and unzip it locally.

Answer (score 0):

1)In case of Ubuntu go files folder (App)
2)at bottom there is option called 'connect to server'
3)paste your server address
4)pop-up box asked for password
5)select anonymous
6)after connection you can directly access all folders as same as another storage device

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows 10 you can simply do that by accessing the FTP through the `windows explorer`.

Answer (score 0):

in terminal, type the following command to download files in the whole directory:
wget -nH -m --ftp-user=your_username --ftp-password=your_password ftp://your_ftp_host/*

Answer (score -2):

I use `WinHTTrack website copier` or `Offline browser`, which download files from site.

Comment: Isn't WinHTTrack used to copy websites?   I personally suggest using a client such as filezilla considering there are lots of files to grab via FTP.    https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Using and https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Download